# "Sensibly" remove points in a Python list

Tags: python, list, filter, reduce

Suppose I have two arrays indicating the x and y coordinates of a calibration curve.

```
X = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,14,16,18,20,30,40,50]
Y = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,24,28,32,36,40,60,80,100]
```

My example arrays above contain 18 points. You'll notice that the x values are not linearly spaced; there are more points at lower values of x.

Let's suppose I need to reduce the number of points in my calibration curve to 13 points. Obviously, I could just remove the first five or the last five points, but that would shorten my overall range of x values. To maintain range and minimise the space between x values I would preferentially remove values x= 2,4,6,8,10. Removing these x points and their respective y values would leave 13 points in the curve as required.

How could I do this point selection and removal automatically in Python? I.e. Is there an algorithm to pick the best x points from a list, where "best" is defined as keeping the points as close as possible while keeping the overall range and adhering to the new number of points.

Please note that the points remaining must be in the original lists, so I can't interpolate the 18 points on to a 13 point grid.

Comment: Sorry - I've edited my original question to (hopefully!) clarify things. Basically I want to reduce the number of values but keep over overall range (i.e. Min x and max x). To achieve this I'd like to remove close lying points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 30, 40, 50]
Y = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 60, 80, 100]

assert len(X) == len(set(X)), "Duplicate X values found"

points = list(zip(X, Y))
points.sort()  # sorts by X

while len(points) > 13:
    # Find index whose neighbouring X values are closest together
    i = min(range(1, len(points) - 1), key=lambda p: points[p + 1][0] - points[p - 1][0])
    points.pop(i)

print(points)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2), (3, 6), (5, 10), (7, 14), (10, 20), (12, 24), (14, 28), (16, 32), (18, 36), (20, 40), (30, 60), (40, 80), (50, 100)]
```

If you want the original series again:

```
X, Y = zip(*points)
```

Answer (score 3):

This would maximize the square root distances between the chosen points.  It in some sense spreads the points as far as possible.

```
import itertools
list(max(itertools.combinations(sorted(X), 13), i
         key=lambda l: sum((a - b) ** 2 for a, b in zip(l, l[1:]))))
```

Note that this is only feasible for small problems.  The time complexity for selecting k points is `O(k * (len(X) choose k))`, so basically `O(exp(len(X))`.  So don't even think about using this for, e.g., `len(X) == 100` and `k == 10`.

Comment: That is a very clever idea with an intuitive motivation, so +1. For the given problem size it will work well, although of course it will quickly become infeasible if 18 becomes much larger. I'm not quite sure how you would compute this in such cases. Perhaps some hill-climbing approach would work or at least provide a reasonable heuristic.

Comment: Of course you're right. I added a note to the answer.

Comment: It is still a good criterion, even for the 100, 10 case. You would just need a non-brute force way to find it, or, failing that, at least approximate it.

Answer (score 0):

An algorithm that would achieve that:

1. Convert each number into the sum of the absolute difference to the number to the left and to the right. If a number is missing, first or last cases, then use MAX_INT. For example, 1 would become MAX_INT; 2 would become 2, 10 would become 3.
2. Remove the first case with the lowest sum.
3. If you need to remove more numbers, go to 1.

This would remove 2,4,6,8,10,3,...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive approach that repeatedly removes the point which will be the least missed:

```
def mostRedundantPoint(x):
    #returns the index, i, in the range 0 < i < len(x) - 1
    #that minimizes x[i+1] - x[i-1]
    #assumes len(x) > 2 and that x
    #is sorted in ascending order

    gaps = [x[i+1] - x[i-1] for i in range(1,len(x)-1)]
    i = gaps.index(min(gaps))
    return i+1

def reduceList(x,k):
    if len(x) <= k:
        return x
    else:
        i = mostRedundantPoint(x)
        return reduceList(x[:i]+x[i+1:],k)

X = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,14,16,18,20,30,40,50]
print(reduceList(X,13))
#prints [1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

This list essentially agrees with your intended output since 7 vs. 8 have the same net effect. It is reasonably quick in the sense that it is almost instantaneous in reducing `sorted([random.randint(1,10**6) for i in range(1000)])` from 1000 elements to 100 elements. The fact that it is recursive implies that it will blow the stack if you try to remove many more points than that, but with what seems to be your intended problem size that shouldn't be an issue. If need be, you could of course replace the recursion by a loop.